# Can't filter empty cells in sumprod

Tags: excel-formula, sumproduct

I copy values from another sheet on my main sheet like so `=mySheet!D2&""`  `=mySheet!D3&""`  etc

The thing is when I try to do a SUMPROD on cells that are empty in mySheet it breaks.

`=SOMMEPROD((mySheet!D2:D151)*(mySheet!G2:G151))`  OK

`=SOMMEPROD((mySheet!D2:D152)*(mySheet!G2:G152))`  NOK because mySheet!D152 is empty

`=SI(ET(D151="";G151="");0;D151*G151)` is the check I need for each cells processed in SUMPROD
but I can't find a way to mix the two formula.

Sadly `=SOMMEPROD(--(mySheet!D3:D152<>"")*mySheet!G3:G152)` is giving a wrong result.

I can fix that in VBA but I'd like to learn to do it with formula.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: try `=SOMMEPROD((mySheet!D2:D151);(mySheet!G2:G151))`

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply Scott. I am looking for a dynamic solution that will take in account the new entries in the D column in the future without having to change it in my SUMPROD formula.

Comment: that should do it, it should ignore blanks and text as I wrote it.

Comment: It does not, if I delete D151's content the formula breaks.

Comment: just make the ranges large enough for future expansion

Comment: This is my intention but again it breaks on empty cell.

Comment: it does not for me. If you replace the `*` with `;`: `=SOMMEPROD((mySheet!D2:D180);(mySheet!G2:G180))`

Comment: Switching * to ; does make the error goes away but result becomes 0.

Comment: Then your numbers are stored as text.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My columns were Standard, I have put them as Numbers but no luck.

Comment: Changing the formatting does not change the value.

Comment: Indeed, VALUE() did the job. But to use VALUE I have to get rid of the &"" in my tab declaration. If I do so it works even without using VALUE() but I would like to keep the zeros hidden.